# Changing cv but still keeping same font size

Tags: formatting, fontsize, templates, cv, awesome-cv

I am using an online template to create my resume.

[image]

In my technical skills, I want it to be the same as experience, but without the instutition, the degree, the location, and date.

The code is as follows:

```
\begin{cventries}
\cventry
{Degree} % Degree
{Institution} % Institution
{Location} % Location
{Date} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Point 1}
\item {Point 2}
\item {Point 3}
\item {Point 4}
\end{cvitems}
}
\end{cventries}
```

If I just want the points, I change my code to the following:

```
\begin{cventries}
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Point 1}
\item {Point 2}
\item {Point 3}
\item {Point 4}
\end{cvitems}
\end{cventries}
```

but then my text size becomes like this, way bigger:

[image]

I don't want all the extra cventry stuff, and so after I remove it, I still want the text size to be the same as before. The text size of the points should not be altered.

The template I am using:

https://www.latextemplates.com/template/awesome-resume-cv

Answer (score 1):

**First way)**

Try to place `cvitems` inside `\descriptionstyle`. This is how `cventries` environment uses the `cvitems` as shown in your cventry definition.

Code:

```
\cvsection{technical skills}

\begin{cventries}
{\descriptionstyle{
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Point 1}
\item {Point 2}
\item {Point 3}
\item {Point 4}
\end{cvitems}}
}
\end{cventries}
```

**Second way)** Just  try to give the `\cvitems` inside an empty `\cventry` but then you have to add the `vspace` manually like:

```
\cvsection{technical skills}\vspace{-4.0mm}

\begin{cventries}
\cventry
{}
{}
{}
{}
{
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Point 1}
\item {Point 2}
\item {Point 3}
\item {Point 4}
\end{cvitems}
}
\end{cventries}
```

If you don't like the result of first way (because it will probably change the margins use the second way)

Result:

[image]